# How to prevent falling for Jingle-Jangle fallacies?

Tags: measurement, terminology, experimental-psychology

What are some ways to avoid the Jingle-Jangle fallacies when it comes to choosing a form of measurement in psychology research?

Comment: This question might be a bit broad ... can you narrow it down to say, survey questionnaires, or machine learning research, or verbal exercises, or whatever you have in mind...?

Comment: I was thinking in terms of selecting a method of measurement for a research study. Can be questionnaires if that narrows it down even more, but not exclusively restricted to that way of measure.

Comment: Factor analysis and structural equation modeling.

Comment: What are Jingle-Jangle fallacies? can you give an example? it's good practice to frame your question with examples, provide web links to essential terminology etc.